# Loading different PowerShell profiles on startup? [Powershell 7]

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to specify which PowerShell profile to load when initializing PowerShell?

For instance, I'd like to be able to load a Python Conda profile when working in Python, or load a profile with bash command aliases when working with cross-platform scripts.

Note: I'm on the same machine, on the same user. So machine/user-specific profiles would not work in my case.

Comment: How do you want to invoke the different profiles? By typing in a command, by clicking on a shortcut, by beeing prompted with a choice on startup, ...?

Comment: you may be able to do some customizing with >>> about_PowerShell_Config - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_config?view=powershell-7 <<<

Comment: @Thomas Any is fine. I was initially considering either a command to run in the current session, or an argument to `pwsh` to be used in Windows Terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PowerShell profiles are just PowerShell scripts loaded on startup of the PowerShell terminal, there are multiple ways to load them. Assuming you have two profile files:

- conda_profile.ps1
- bash_profile.ps1

**Calling the profile scripts directly**

You can just execute them after you open a PowerShell window, e. g.:

```
.\conda_profile.ps1
```

**Calling the profile scripts by aliases**

If the names or paths are too long or too complicated, you can create aliases for them, e. g.:

```
# Put the following two lines into the file stored in $PROFILE. You probably have to create it.
Set-Alias -Name condap -Value "C:\path\to\conda_profile.ps1"
Set-Alias -Name bashp -Value "C:\path\to\bash_profile.ps1"
```

After that, you can load a profile by typing `condap` or `bashp`.

**Calling a profile by shortcut**

You can also create different shortcuts to open a PowerShell with a certain profile:

1. Copy the shortcut from `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk`
2. Rename it to `condap` for example.
3. Edit its target from `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` to `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -File "C:\path\to\conda_profile.ps1"`.

Do it for other profiles respectively.

**Choosing a profile by being prompted at startup**

You can also write a profile that asks you to choose between different profiles, when you start PowerShell. Make sure you have a profile for your current host and current user:

```
if (!(Test-Path -Path $PROFILE)) {
    New-Item -Type File -Path $PROFILE -Force
}
```

After that, add some lines to this file to ask for input and execute the desired profile script based on that input. It will work, but keep in mind that a user interaction inside the profile will probably be a bad design in the most cases.

Comment: Omg, I can't believe I missed that profiles are actually PS scripts themselves! Your Option 1 "Calling the profile scripts by aliases" is perfect if I want to activate it in an existing session. Your Option 2 "Calling a profile by shortcut" is also great for creating a new Windows Terminal profile with conda in Powershell.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be more concise for command line (and non-windows) users:

`pwsh -NoExit -File <your_profile_script>`

Will start a powershell session with the specified profile.